SSAS Tabular Model Date Relationship Does Not Work For Some tables in Power BI
I have created SSAS Tabular Model, in this model there is a date dimension table.
After connecting to the model in Power BI, I am facing a problem that the Date relationship is working for some tables, but not for others.
I have made sure that the relationship is created on the correct fields, ensured that the relationship fields from both sides are of data type (Date) with the same format (M/d/yyyy), and all relationships are active.
I have also made sure that there are no slicers or filters affecting the behavior.
Below you can see a highlight of 2 tables, one of them works as intended with the date dimension, while the other doesn't.

The yellow outline shows the date dimension, the green outline shows a table that works successfully with the date dimension, the red outline shows a table that does not work with the date dimension.
Below you can see the result when I create 2 tables in Power BI with 2 columns, the year column from the date dimension, and a numerical value from the highlighted tables.

As you can see, the relationship works for the second one, but not for the first one.

Are you sure your date dimension contain an interval of years/dates aligned with your fact table ?

The blank row in that visual aggregates all the fact rows that don't match any row in the dimension table.  So you've got a data issue, or the relationships are configured incorrectly.
